# Dúvida sobre a utilização do chosen-select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia

Pessoal estou utilizando o **chosen-select** em meu projeto do seguinte link: [Link do Projeto Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)

Bom até ai nenhuma novidade, porém no meu projeto eu tenho um arquivo **sysfly.php** (página que já possui um **chosen-select** funcionando) e tenho um outro chamado **sysflyajax.php**(nesse eu tenho algumas rotinas para popular uma div do **sysfly.php**.

Em **sysflyajax.php** eu tenho um select que prentendo utilizar o **chosen-select**, porém quando eu coloco no class desse select ele não é exibido, quando tiro a referencia do **chosen-select form-control** ele é exibido.

Eu observei o seguinte quando eu coloco **chosen-select form-control** no arquivo **sysfly.php** ele faz o seguinte:

```html
<select id="EntFilterZ2" name="EntFilters2[]" multiple="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 chosen-select form-control" data-placeholder="Selecione os filtros desejados" style="display: none;">
                <option>eder</option>
                <option>luca</option>
                <option>luiz</option>
            </select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" title="" id="EntFilterZ2_chosen" style="width: 998px;"><ul class="chosen-choices">
  <li class="search-field">
    <input class="chosen-search-input default" type="text" id="inpFilter" autocomplete="off" value="Selecione os filtros desejados" style="width: 2px;">
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
</div></div>
```

No meu código mesmo eu realmente criei as linhas do select à porém automaticamente ele montou outros elementos como mostrado acima **.**

Porém no meu select que eu montei dentro do arquivo **sysflyajax.php** ele não monta as demais linhas automaticamente logo ele não funciona.

Alguém saberia me informar do porque desse comportamento? Só para ficar mais claro no **sysflyajax.php** é o local onde eu uso o php para buscar informações no banco de dados mysql e o select que vou usar o **chosen-select** fica armazenado em uma variável, porém como disse se uso no class o chosen-select o select não é exibido.

Infelizmente não consigo postar o código das páginas visto que é um sistema de um cliente e não posso divulgar o mesmo, precisava entender o porque desse comportamento .

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia

Respondendo minha dúvida para resolver meu problema bastou colocar em uma função javascript eu coloquei o seguinte comando:

$('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: '100%' });
                $('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });

Onde resolveu meu problema em definitivo agradeço à todos.